# SQL SUM large equation to get product net price

Tags: php, mysql, sql

## What I am trying to do:

I am trying to SUM product net price.
The product have ***sold price and discount in %*** also this product is related to export invoice which MAY have ***discount in % and TAX***.

Here are my fields for the products:

- `sold_products.sold_price` (Product selling price)
- `sold_products.quantity` (Product sold quantity)
- `sold_products.discount` ( Discount for the product in %)

Here are my fields for the invoice related to a product:

- `export_invoices.discount` (Discount for the invoice in %)
- `export_invoices.tax` (Tax for the invoice in %)

## What I have tried to do

```
    sum(
  ( (sold_products.sold_price - (sold_products.sold_price * (sold_products.discount / 100))) * sold_products.quantity )
) as total
```

This works fine but I just calculated the product price after discount (Only PART 1) I need take the result from the query above and add invoice calculates to it.

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your post

Comment: `SELECT 
export_invoices.discount, 
export_invoices.tax, 
 SUM(
  ( (sold_products.sold_price - (sold_products.sold_price * (sold_products.discount / 100))) * sold_products.quantity )
) AS total
FROM export_invoices
LEFT JOIN sold_products ON sold_products.product_id = export_invoices.product_id` didn't joining table will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly model how invoices typically work, you want to round the price for each product before summing.  The second parameter to round is the number of decimal places to round to; the vast majority of currencies use two decimals.  If you are dealing with rarer currencies, adjust accordingly. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes shows currencies using 0, 3, or 4 decimals.

And no need to repeat sold price twice.  Instead of `amount - amount * discount / 100` you can say the mathematically equivalent `amount * (1 - discount / 100)` or `amount * (100 - discount) / 100` which becomes much simpler when the amount is itself a complex expression, as it will be when applying the invoice discount and tax.

So the product total is:

```
sum(round(sold_products.sold_price * (1 - sold_products.discount / 100), 2) * sold_products.quantity)
```

Or, if the discount is applied to the quantity, not the per item price:

```
sum(round(sold_products.sold_price * sold_products.quantity * (1 - sold_products.discount / 100), 2))
```

These will produce different answers; figure out which you want.  For example, with price 1, discount 33, and quantity 10, the former will give 6.70 (10 times a discounted per item price of .67) while the latter will give 6.67 (33 percent off the total product price of 10).

Then take that sum and apply the discount and tax (rounding at each step):

```
round(round(sum(...) * (1 - export_invoices.discount / 100), 2) * (1 + export_invoices.tax / 100), 2)
```

From your use of sum, I'm assuming you are grouping by invoice.

You ask "If export_invoices.tax is a boolean value which mean 0 not exists and 1 exists and if exists then number query should multiply 1.14".  That would be:

```
round(round(sum(...) * (1 - export_invoices.discount / 100), 2) * if(export_invoices.tax, 1.14, 1), 2)
```

Comment: So what are the the numbers u used which are `1 and 2`?

Comment: Updated answer explaining the 1 and 2

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time that was really helpful

Comment: One more question please. If `export_invoices.tax` is a boolean value which mean 0 not exists and 1 exists and if exists then number query should multiply 1.14

Comment: Updated for boolean tax

Comment: OMG! I want to accept your answer twice :D
thanks alot